# If/else statement doesn't work in jQuery as I think it should

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have the exercise to code a tic-tac-toe game. I was, just, trying some ideas when I came to this problem. My function doesn't work and it is very simple if/else statement.

```
function game(){
if(e = "x"){     
  d.text("o");      
   }else{
  c.text("o");      
   }  
  };
```

Whatever field I hit it returns "o" into *d*. Also when I change `if(e = "x")` to `if(e == "x")` it always returns "o" into *c*.

I will appreciate any kind of hint. Thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = $("#a"),
    b = $("#b"),
    c = $("#c"),
    d = $("#d"),
    e = $("#e"),
    f = $("#f"),
    g = $("#g"),
    h = $("#h"),
    i = $("#i");

  function game() {
    if (e = "x") {
      d.text("o");
    } else {
      c.text("o");
    }
  };


  function humanIsX() {
    $(".field").on("click", function() {
      $(this).text("x");
      game();
    });
  };
  humanIsX();
});
```

```css
.field {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 110px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="third_page">
  <div class="row" id="first-row">
    <div class="field" id="a"></div>
    <div class="field" id="b"></div>
    <div class="field" id="c"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="second-row">
    <div class="field" id="d"></div>
    <div class="field" id="e"></div>
    <div class="field" id="f"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="third-row">
    <div class="field" id="g"></div>
    <div class="field" id="h"></div>
    <div class="field" id="i"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are your `game` and `humanIsX` functions defined within your `document.ready` function?

Comment: @SamAxe -  It's a routine, I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, there's a massive difference between `=` which is *assignment* and `==` which is *comparison*.

Another problem is that `e` is not a value like `"x"` but instead a DOM object you'll need to interrogate:

```
if (e.text() == "x")
```

You'll probably want to rework this into some kind of array instead of a heap of variables which isn't scalable. Then you can work with it more programmatically, skipping the `if` entirely. Code with fewer branches is more predictable.

For example, name your cells `#cell-1` through `#cell-9` and then you can reference them with `$('#cell-' + cellNo).text('o')` instead.

Comment: I can't vote for your answer, yet. But I would. I've already prepared some arrays and will try to skip the if statement. Probably, I will be back here for more help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Change your conditional to

```
if (e=="x") {
```

Answer (score 0):

$("#e") returns an html object. If you want to see if there is an "x" in the div, do this $("#e").text() == "x".

```
function game() {
  if (e.text() == "x") {
    d.text("o");
  } else {
    c.text("o");
  }
};
```

1. Add .text to e
2. Change "=" to "=="